# Do we need the 'car' tag?

Tags: discussion, tags

As above - it seems fairly superfluous!

Of course, that above sentence is too short... So I'll add this bit to make it pass the automated check...

Answer (score 2):

I agree it is superfluous :D (I love that word).

I believe this should be deleted with the intent to move the questions associated with it to other tags which make more sense. I mean, if it was car identification it wouldn't fall directly under "car" ... it's an ID question, tag it as such. Anything else is plain idiotic to me.

Answer (score 2):

There are other offenders (stats as of today):

58 x [car](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/car) questions

32 x [truck](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/truck) questions

2 x [pick-up](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/pick-up) questions ([this gem's](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/15676/how-you-call-pickup-trucks-trunk-cover) tagged with all three!)

268 x [motorcycle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycle) questions

---

I can understand why folks might tag a question as [motorcycle](https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/motorcycle), but I'm not entirely convinced it is useful when the make and model are clearly specified.

Comment: You can't categorize by year/make/model, so motorcycle is useful to say that it's specific to two wheels. By that logic however, we also need a specific to four wheels tag...

Comment: Motorcycle is specific to a type. For instance, you could mark a car or a motorcycle with the Suzuki tag. Motorcycle delineates. It also makes it much easier for those who have a specific thing for them to find them easy. DucatiKiller comes to mind quite readily here, lol. The other three are *definitely* superfluous, IMHO.

Comment: It is useful so people can *subscribe* to the motorcycle tab and motorcycle experts can look just for motorcycle questions.